# Visual Studio crashes upon opening two XMl files

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, crash, nuget

I've started getting an odd problem with Visual Studio 2010 crashing. I wondered if anyone has seen this?

I first noticed the problem trying to use the NuGet package manager to add some libraries to a project (actually Moq and Machine.Specifications). Upon adding the second package, Visual Studio would crash. It doesn't matter what order the packages are added or to which solution. Whenever I try to add a package to a solution that already has a NuGet package- .

After some more prodding, I noticed that in fact opening any two XML files causes the same symptoms - crash! To repro this, I can create a new Windows Console App solution, add two XML files to the solution (accepting the default names and content). Then when I open the files, upon opening the second file -  - visual studio crashes. WTF?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim, I really can't remember to well but try reloading the latest MSXML, which I think maybe version 6.

Comment: Hi Rob. Too late! I had already uninstalled VS. It had some other things wrong with it too, like some of the code refactoring templates missing. I've reinstalled and applied SP1 and so far things seem to be better.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't reproduce with my Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  Try launching visual studio with safemode (devenv.exe /safemode)?  This will load visual studio minus 3rd party extensions -- see if it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and it was fixed by a repair of the Visual Studio installation.
Rob may indeed me correct but I didn't try a repair of the MSXML installation first.